# Как получить информацию о свободном месте на диске сервера в локальной сети?

Tags: c#, linux, windows

Есть какой-то способ получить информацию о заполненности диска на сервере в локальной сети? Если это Windows-сервер, то можно воспользоваться WMI, я думаю. А как быть с Linux-серверами? Есть какой-то общий способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если на сервере запрещена установка, софта, то можно по ssh , получать информацию. (Для автоматизации при большом парке,можно использовать ansible)

Если разрешена, можно поставить агента который будет отдавать метрики диска, тут разброс огромный
От простых snmp, node-export до подключения к системам мониторинга (zabbix, prometeus, prtg)

Comment: `можно по ssh` так: логинимся, даём `df`, парсим ?

Comment: Да `df -h | grep '^/dev'`

Comment: Поддержу про системы мониторинга. Чем тот же zabbix не устроил? Потому что щас ты научишься дёргать место, потом тебе захочется дёрнуть загрузку проца в течении дня, а потом появится мысль, что неплохо бы это всё отправлять на сервер, чтобы централизованно хранить статистику и в итоге ты придумаешь монстра Франкенштейна, который будет выполнять вроде то же самое, но "есть нюанс"